# ASP.NET webforms action a xss threat?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, xss, antixsslibrary

I am currently working on locking down an application that is reporting XSS vulnerabilities for a website.

The site is built for ASP.NET 2.0, but has been upgraded to function within the ASP.NET 4.0 libraries.

I have scanned the site with a security tool, and have pages reporting to be open to a XSS (reflected) attack.

I have noticed that it seems possible on any webpage to include JavaScript against the QueryString parameters, as ASP.NET will automatically append this onto the page's form's action.

Now, if ValidateResponse is on, and the JavaScript in the URL is basic, then the page will error, as expected.
If the JavaScript is encoded, then it seems that ValidateResponse misses it, driving the security testing app to throw an error as the test passes through to the HTML.

As an example:

```
The url /product.aspx?ProductGuid=1234
Case 1:  /product.aspx?ProductGuid=<script>alert(1);</script>
    In this case, ValidateResponse picks up the pieces, and errors for you.
Case 2:  product.aspx?ProductGuid=%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E
    In this case, ValidateResponse sees no issue.
    The JavaScript is pushed through to the browser by ASP.NET itself, in the form's action.
```

I understand the concept of false positives, and maybe .NET ensures that URL in the action is correctly encoded, but I am not sure since I can't find anything definitive on it.

Is this type of issue a false positive?
If not, how can the form's action be correctly sanitized?

I cannot seem to even find this question asked but in a few places, and nowhere that I found my general question was there ever an answer.

Thank you all for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried running the test the security application identified as an issue? What happens when you access /product.aspx?ProductGuid=%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E ? I'd check this in Firefox and ensure the browser's XSS filter is disabled. If the attack string is reflected in the response and Javascript executes, then there is a legitimate vulnerability.

Comment: MrWerbenjagermanjensen, thank you.

I have run it through the browser, and it does reflect in the HTML response.  It doesn't execute as far as I can tell however.
Now, this may be just because I don't have the encoding 100% right, but it doesn't give me convincing evidence that this is a false positive.

The fact is, ASP.NET will take the URL and put it into the form's action.
I cannot control this.
I cannot be the only one with this problem though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET. Is the issue that forms are POSTing to the same URL as the form, and including extra URL parameters in the URL when getting the form causes those parameters to be echoed in the HTML for the form?

Comment: So as an example, if the URL was `/product.aspx?param=val`, then the form HTML would include `<form action="/product.aspx?param=val">` ?

Comment: MrWerbenjagermanjensen, yes this is the case.
ASP.NET automatically adds the URL into the form action.  In webforms there is only one form per page, and it is managed by MS.  When it creates the page, the URL is the action, including any malformed or malicious content.

Comment: I don't think URL encoding is quite sufficient to stop XSS in the postback URL. I'd consult OWASP's XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes) on how to properly sanitize those parameters, you'll need to use HTML entity encoding. I'm not sure how to go about that in ASP.NET